# Dismiss dialog after screen orientation change

Tags: android

1) I launch a background task (via AsyncTask)

```
new FindJourneyTask().execute(); // FindJourneyTask extends AsyncTask
```

2) Still in the main thread (just before new thread is launched) I create a dialog with showDialog(dialogId)

```
// this method is in FindJourneyTask
protected void onPreExecute() {
    showDialog(DIALOG_FINDING_JOURNEY);
}
```

3) Screen orientation changes and the Activity is recreated

4) How can I now dismiss the dialog from the FindJourneyTask? Calling dismissDialog(dialogId) does nothing.

```
// this method is in FindJourneyTask
protected void onPostExecute(FindJourneyResult result) {
    dismissDialog(DIALOG_FINDING_JOURNEY); // does nothing
}
```

Comment: Post your code so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a common problem, and there are no real good solutions.  The issue is that on screen orientation change, the entire Activity is destroyed and recreated.  At the same time, the Dialog you previously had is re-created in the new Activity, but the old background task still refers to the old Activity when it tries to dismiss the dialog.  The result is that it dismisses a dialog which was long ago destroyed, rather than dismissing the dialog the new orientation created.

There are three basic solutions:

1. Override the default orientation-handling code so that your Activity is not destroyed upon rotation.  This is probably the least satisfactory answer, as it blocks a lot of code that is automatically run upon orientation changes.
2. Create a static member variable of your Activity that references the Activity itself, so you can call `STATIC_ACTIVITY_VARIABLE.dismissDialog()`.
3. Code a solution in which the background task keeps track of the current Activity and updates itself as necessary.

These three solutions are discussed at length here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bf046b95cf38832d/

Comment: I made my dialog a static variable within my activity, and it works perfect now. e.g. static AlertDialog dlg_error = null;

Answer (score 11):

There is a better solution to this problem now which involves using fragments.

If you create a dialog using DialogFragment, then this fragment will be responsible for maintaining your dialog's lifecycle. When you show a dialog, you supply a tag for your fragment ([DialogFragment.show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show%28android.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String))). When you need to access your dialog, you just look for the necessary DialogFragment using [FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)) instead of having a reference to the dialog itself.

This way if device changes orientation, you will get a new fragment instead of the old one, and everything will work.

Here's some code based also in @peresisUser answer:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) context;
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
   DialogFragment dialogFragment = (DialogFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("your_dialog_tag");
   if(dialogFragment!=null) {
      Dialog dialog = dialogFragment.getDialog();
      if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing()) {
         dialogFragment.dismiss();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I got the same problem even using fragments. When the activity is recreated and try to find the fragment by tag, I always get a null reference with the dialog shown in the new activity O_o

Comment: @fr4gus This is probably a bug, you'll have to experiment with things in order to find a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

This is long after the question was asked and answered, but i stumbled upon this problem also and wanted to share my solution...

I check in onSavedInstance() which runs on orientation change, whether the dialog is showing or not with dialog.isShowing(), and pass it into outState variable. Then in your onCreate(), you check this var if it's true. If it is, you simply dismiss your dialog with dialog.dismiss()

Hope this helps others :()

Comment: why you don't dismiss the dialog in onSavedInstance :)?

Answer (score 2):

I tried adding `setRetainInstance(true);` on `OnCreate` function of `DialogFragment`. This will cause dialog to dismiss on rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to specific activity in your Manifest to solve this problem            `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"`

**like this,**

```
        <activity
            android:name=".PDFTools"
            android:exported="false"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.DocScanner.NoActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simplified workaround:

```
public class RenameDeckDialog extends DialogFragment{
      
  private final boolean isRotated;
  
  // This constructor is used to recreation after screen rotation
  public RenameDeckDialog() {
    // Dimiss on screen rotation
    isRotated = true;
  }
  
  // This constructor is used for initialization for the first time
  public RenameDeckDialog(your params) {
    this.deckDbPath = deckDbPath;
    isRotated = false;
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isRotated) dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).